# Why does Release not build though Debug goes, but only for one of the projects using the same source file?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, xilinx, vivado

The C++ compiler for Xilinx SDK, compiling code for a Zynq SoC (an ARM core), complains about an uninitialized variable, but only in the Release build, and only for one project.  Debug is fine, and both Debug and Release builds are fine for another project linking to the same source file newthing.cpp.  There are no project-dependent #ifdefs that I can see.  As far as I can tell, all the build settings are the same, except of course debug info and optimization are different between Release and Debug, but not different between projects.  One of us suspects a bug in Xilinx tools, but possibly there's a subtle difference somewhere other than the obvious places such as makefiles or Build Settings in the IDE.

The trouble is in code like this (in newthing.cpp):

```
Result R;
GetSomeResult(7, R);
PushData(R.blip);     <== compiler whines: using uninitialized var
```

where the newthing.h header defines

```
struct Result
{
    int blip;
    int bloop;
};
```

and the Result struct, defined elsewhere in newthing.cpp, is filled in like this:

```
int GetSomeResult(int n, Result &res)
{
   res.blip = n + 100;
   res.bloop = 50;
   return n;
}
```

Note that I'm ignoring the return value from GetSomeResult, but I doubt that's relevant.

Comment: As a wild guess, consider moving `GetSomeResult` definition *before* the "erroneous" code (which is **significantly** simplified, I suppose).

Comment: Even in most conventional environments, I still experience such problems from time to time - the key point here is intializing the structure as a side effect of a function. The compilers just tend to stop def-use analysis at some point for their own reasons.

Comment: We have found the problem to be in a compiler option, -Wno-maybe-uninitialized, given in a makefile for building a static library for one project, but absent in the makefile for the other. This is not the main makefile, so took more digging to find.  The option only affects Release builds. We don't want to change the build system, so we're going with a workaround in the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a false negative.

If you can, just zero-initialise the structure before you pass it to `GetSomeResult`:

```
Result R = {};
GetSomeResult(7, R);
PushData(R.blip);
```

If that's not feasible (in very rare cases it may be too slow/wasteful), you'll have to use your build system or a `#pragma` to turn off that warning/error for this translation unit.

You may also wish to try with a newer version of your compiler, if possible.

Of course, your code would be more idiomatic and not susceptible to this problem if you dropped the C-like approach and instead wrote:

```
Result GetSomeResult(const int n)
{
   Result res;
   res.blip = n + 100;
   res.bloop = 50;
   return res;
}

// const Result R = GetSomeResult(7);
// PushData(R.blip);
```

Comment: We're reluctant to change the makefiles or anything in the build system, since that could mess up others. Adding an empty constructor looks like the best approach for now.

Comment: @DarenW: It already has an "empty" implicitly-defined constructor; you do not need to (and should not) add a constructor (and, if you do, it'll have to be not-empty in order to fix this problem). You should instead do what I suggested.